# When developing a multi-platform mobile app, what the available options with their pros/cons?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, windows-phone, multiplatform

In my mobile app that I plan to develop, it would needs access to the compass, maps, integration with phone functionality (like silencing the phone with user permission of course when in this app), notifications, etc.

**Most important** I need the application to be available on the major platforms like iOS, BB, Android, Windows & Symbian at the least.

I have been pointed to http://cordova.apache.org/ but have no experience with it.

**OR**

Is developing with the native language for each platform still the best bet?

Comment: It depends on which platform you choose.There are many sdk available which allow app development in multiple platforms.I prefer single platform app development.

Comment: I think that trying to target iOS, BB, Android, Windows & Symbian is too broad. You won't find any SDK that will cover all of them. Try narrowing it down. My preference is single platform per app.

Comment: @Simon i think you dont know about hybrid mobile app development,
i recommend you to read about it on internet..
Because Hybrid app development has it's own advantages like:
Write you application logic once for multiple platform, Cost effectiveness, write UI in HTML and Javascript and Get Native UI on each different platform, and many more.
But Only for Very high rich UI requirement you should give preference to single platform development like gaming..etc.

Comment: @shriduttkothari as I said thats my preference. We could go for years debating cross platform vs native, and no one would prove anything. I dislike cross platform solutions and can spot their shortcomings a mile away. But thats my experience, I'm sure that there are scenarios in which cross platform will be better suited. I tend to always do native as much as I need to.

Comment: The most problems I've faced in phonegap application is performance issue like transition from one screen to another. Though after i started using angular and backbone js which have improved my applications a lot. But still they lack the smoothness and performance of native app..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can Use `PhoneGap`

Adwantages:

```
    Open Source and comes under MIT license (Free software license)
    Based on best known web technologies HTML5, JavaScript, CSS3
    Essey to use.
    Uses Javascript as a bridge between native API and browser
    Provides JavaScript APIs to access native features inside embedded web browser
    Supported mobile platforms –
    > ios,android,windows phone,blackberry,webos,symbian,bada
    PhoneGap Build (Write once, Compile in Cloud, Run anywhere)
    Developer can also create custom plugins
    PhoneGap also provides API Documentation ([http://docs.phonegap.com][1])
```

Disadvantages:
nothing but you must know javascript,html5,css3.

Comment: Some other options are:
appcelerator,cony,appfurnace,Mosync,appclouud,antina,netbuiscuits,Appspress..etc.

Answer (score 0):

Some other options are:

- appcelerator
- cony
- appfurnace
- Mosync
- appclouud
- antina
- netbuiscuits
- Appspress
- etc

But the most useful, awesome is PhoneGap (created by Adobe)

Go and search on internet with keyword `Hybrid mobile application Development`.
You will get few more options and also more details about them.

But trust me PhoneGap is really cool.

Comment: PhoneGap was created by Nitobi, which was bought by Adobe in 2011.